# how to reference dict variable values on mysql query in python

Tags: python

I am working on mysql connector using python i am using dict `{'invoice.approved_on': {'to': '2018-1-11 23:59:00', 'from': '2017-5-13 00:00:00'}`  but i'm not sure how to reference it on query i tried with `%(invoice.approved_on[from])s AND %(invoice.approved_on[to])s)` like this but its not working please let me know how to reference dict values on query in python

```
cursor = self.conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT invoice.`id` AS `invoice.id` from invoice where invoice.`approved_on` BETWEEN %(invoice.approved_on[from])s AND %(invoice.approved_on[to])s) GROUP BY invoice.id', {'invoice.approved_on': {'to': '2018-1-11 23:59:00', 'from': '2017-5-13 00:00:00'})
```

here i need to know how to reference `from` and `to` inside the query like invoice.approved_on[from] or invoice.approved_on.from or invoice.approved_on.0

its throwing some error like below

```
 [ERROR] 2018-06-24 16:03:06,701 <erp.accounts.reportsQueryBuilder> 'invoice.approved_on.0'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charles/PycharmProjects/2.8/XSerp/util/reportsQueryBuilder.py", line 183, in select
    ), where)
  File "/home/charles/.virtualenvs/venvpython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 185, in execute
    for key, item in args.iteritems())
KeyError: 'invoice.approved_on.0'
[ERROR] 2018-06-24 16:03:06,703 <erp.middleware> Exception Handling: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: sure i will add minimal code @jpp

Answer (score 0):

```
your_dict = {'invoice.approved_on': {'to': '2018-1-11 23:59:00', 'from': '2017-5-13 00:00:00'}
cursor.execute(f'SELECT invoice.`id` AS `invoice.id` from invoice where invoice.`approved_on` BETWEEN {your_dict['invoice.approved_on']['from']} AND {your_dict['invoice.approved_on']['to']} ) GROUP BY invoice.id')
```

if you are using python3, you can use fstrings listed above

In case youre are using python2 (seems like you are) or need backwards compatibility, use .format()

```
your_dict = {'invoice.approved_on': {'to': '2018-1-11 23:59:00', 'from': '2017-5-13 00:00:00'}
cursor.execute('SELECT invoice.`id` AS `invoice.id` from invoice where invoice.`approved_on` BETWEEN {} AND {} ) GROUP BY invoice.id'.format(your_dict['invoice.approved_on']['from'], your_dict['invoice.approved_on']['to'])
```